# RDotNet Dataframe Query

Tags: c#, r, visual-studio-2013, r.net

I have just started to use the `rdotNet` from: http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/.  I have never used R itself before but can do simple arithmetic in it. I have been able to create the instance and do some of the simple numeric calculations in c#. My issue is when i read in a csv file and create the `dataframe`. The information is all loaded correctly and I can see it when i debug.

When I try to go though the dataframe and print the contents to the screen, the 1st iteration shows me the correct information but after that it seems just to get numbers instead of the actually information.

Since i can do basic calculations in in the solution I will not write the begging code which will create the instance of the *REngine*. I will show is how I read the file in which i have place in the debug folder of the application:
Location of Downloaded csv file I use: http://www.rqtl.org/sampledata/listeria.csv

```
engine.Evaluate("library(datasets)");

engine.Evaluate("dataset1 <- read.csv(file = \" listeria.csv\", header = TRUE, sep = ',')");

DataFrame dataset1 = engine.GetSymbol("dataset1").AsDataFrame();
```

//Here is the problem

```
for (int row = 0, row < dataset1.RowCount; row++)

{

     for ( int col = 0; col < dataset1.ColumnCount; k++)

     {

        Console.Writeline(dataset1[row,col])

     }

}
```

My question is can someone tell me if I am doing something wrong or is there another way of going through the `Dataframe`  in `RdotNet` to get the information.

Hopefully i have explained everything, If you need more information, please feel free to ask.

Built in :

```
Visual Studio 2013, using a console Application, framework 4.5.1, RdotNet DLL: Vers 1.5.5 and in Win 7 64 Bit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `stringsAsFactors` to FALSE.

```
engine.Evaluate("dataset1 <- read.csv(file = 'listeria.csv', header = TRUE, sep = ',', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. It works perfectly for me. I can now see the information fully when printing to screen. Much appreciated for the assist.